# How to fix compiler error for std module dependency in Deno program?

Tags: dependencies, deno

I know there is a question with the same error on SO, but the answer there doesnt help me: [deno bundle failed. Property 'getIterator' does not exist on type 'ReadableStream<R>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63383328/deno-bundle-failed-property-getiterator-does-not-exist-on-type-readablestrea)

Here is the full error:

❯ deno run --allow-all server.ts
Check file:///Users/hagenek/repos/mock-backend/server.ts
error: TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'getIterator' does not exist on type 'ReadableStream'.
return res.readable.getIterator();
~~~~~~~~~~~
at https://deno.land/std@0.83.0/async/pool.ts:45:23

Here is my server.ts code:

```
import { Application } from "./deps.ts";
import router from "./routes.ts"
const PORT = 4000;
const app = new Application();

app.use(router.routes()); // Pass our router as a middleware
app.use(router.allowedMethods()); // Allow HTTP methods on router

await app.listen({ port: PORT });
console.log(`Server running on PORT: ${PORT}`)
```

Routes.ts:

```
import { Router } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";
import {
    addQuote,
    getQuotes,
    getQuote,
    updateQuote,
    deleteQuote,
} from "./controllers/controller.ts";

interface ReadableStream<R> {
    getIterator(): any
}

const router = new Router(); // Create Router

    router
        .get("/api/quote", getQuotes) // Get all quotes
        .get("/api/quote/:id", getQuote) // Get one quote of quoteID: id
        .post("/api/quote", addQuote) // Add a quote
        .put("/api/quote/:id", updateQuote) // Update a quote
        .delete("/api/quote/:id", deleteQuote); // Delete a quote
    
    export default router;
```

Deps.ts

```
export {
    Application
} from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts"
```

Controller.ts

```
interface Quote {
    _id: { $oid: string };
    quote: string;
    quoteID: string;
    author: string;
}

import {MongoClient} from "https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.22.0/mod.ts";

const URI = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017";

// Mongo Connection Init
const client = new MongoClient();
try {
    await client.connect(URI);
    console.log("Database successfully connected");
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
}

const db = client.database("quotesApp");
const quotes = db.collection<Quote>("quotes");

// DESC: ADD single quote
// METHOD: POST /api/quote
export const addQuote = async ({request, response,}: {
    request: any;
    response: any;
}) => {
    try {
        // If the request has no Body, it will return a 404
        if (!request.hasBody) {
            response.status = 400;
            response.body = {
                success: false,
                msg: "No Data",
            };
        } else {
            // Otherwise, it will try to insert
            // a quote in the DB and respond with 201
            const body = await request.body();
            const quote = await body.value;
            await quotes.insertOne(quote);
            response.status = 201;
            response.body = {
                success: true,
                data: quote,
            };
        }
    } catch (err) {
        response.body = {
            success: false,
            msg: err.toString(),
        };
    }
};

// DESC: GET single quote
// METHOD: GET /api/quote/:id
export const getQuote = async ({
                            params,
                            response,
                        }: {
    params: { id: string };
    response: any;
}) => {
    // Searches for a particular quote in the DB
    const quote = await quotes.findOne({quoteID: params.id});
    // If found, respond with the quote. If not, respond with a 404
    if (quote) {
        response.status = 200;
        response.body = {
            success: true,
            data: quote,
        };
    } else {
        response.status = 404;
        response.body = {
            success: false,
            msg: "No quote found",
        };
    }
};

// DESC: GET all Quotes
// METHOD GET /api/quote
export const getQuotes = async ({response}: { response: any }) => {
    try {
        // Find all quotes and convert them into an Array
        const allQuotes = await quotes.find({}).toArray();
        console.log(allQuotes);
        if (allQuotes) {
            response.status = 200;
            response.body = {
                success: true,
                data: allQuotes,
            };
        } else {
            response.status = 500;
            response.body = {
                success: false,
                msg: "Internal Server Error",
            };
        }
    } catch (err) {
        response.body = {
            success: false,
            msg: err.toString(),
        };
    }
};

// DESC: UPDATE single quote
// METHOD: PUT /api/quote/:id
export const updateQuote = async ({
                               params,
                               request,
                               response,
                           }: {
    params: { id: string };
    request: any;
    response: any;
}) => {
    try {
        // Search a quote in the DB and update with given values if found
        const body = await request.body();
        const inputQuote = await body.value;
        await quotes.updateOne(
            { quoteID: params.id },
            { $set: { quote: inputQuote.quote, author: inputQuote.author } }
        );
        // Respond with the Updated Quote
        const updatedQuote = await quotes.findOne({ quoteID: params.id });
        response.status = 200;
        response.body = {
            success: true,
            data: updatedQuote,
        };
    } catch (err) {
        response.body = {
            success: false,
            msg: err.toString(),
        };
    }
};


// DESC: DELETE single quote
// METHOD: DELETE /api/quote/:id
export const deleteQuote = async ({
                               params,
                               response,
                           }: {
    params: { id: string };
    request: any;
    response: any;
}) => {
    try {
        // Search for the given quote and drop it from the DB
        await quotes.deleteOne({quoteID: params.id});
        response.status = 201;
        response.body = {
            success: true,
            msg: "Product deleted",
        };
    } catch (err) {
        response.body = {
            success: false,
            msg: err.toString(),
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't see where you are trying to use `res.readable.getIterator()` (from the error message in your question's title). Can you also include the code for the module at `./controllers/controller.ts` (and any dependent code, if relevant)? Being able to reproduce your problem would be useful in determining a solution.

Comment: Added more information, hope this helps you to debugg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The problem

You are using an outdated version of [`deno.land/x/mongo`](https://deno.land/x/mongo) (v`0.22.0`, whose dependencies are also outdated and misaligned with Deno's current built-in type libraries).

### The solution

Use a version of the module which is compatible with the version of Deno that you are using.

At the time of writing this answer, Deno stable is at v`1.16.3`, and the latest version of that module is v`0.28.0`: [`https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.28.0`](https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.28.0). They appear to be compatible.

### Explanation

Here's the compiler error from your module:

```
% deno cache server.ts 
Check file:///Users/deno/so-70169022/server.ts
error: TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'getIterator' does not exist on type 'ReadableStream<R>'.
  return res.readable.getIterator();
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std@0.83.0/async/pool.ts:45:23
```

> For reference, here's the version of Deno I'm using:
>
> ```
> % deno --version
> deno 1.16.3 (release, x86_64-apple-darwin)
> v8 9.7.106.5
> typescript 4.4.2
> ```

You can see that the error happens in the module at [`https://deno.land/std@0.83.0/async/pool.ts`](https://deno.land/std@0.83.0/async/pool.ts) (which, unfortunately, you can't edit to fix the problem). Note that it's a module from the `std` library (I'll come back to this).

Here's the module graph for your entrypoint:

> Note: I've removed all of the lines in the output unrelated to the problematic module in order to improve readability

```
% deno info server.ts
local: /Users/deno/so-70169022/server.ts
type: TypeScript
dependencies: 134 unique (total 1.72MB)

file:///Users/deno/so-70169022/server.ts (334B)
└─┬ file:///Users/deno/so-70169022/routes.ts (638B)
  └─┬ file:///Users/deno/so-70169022/controllers/controller.ts (4.24KB)
    └─┬ https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.22.0/mod.ts (113B)
      └─┬ https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.22.0/deps.ts (783B)
        └─┬ https://deno.land/std@0.83.0/node/_crypto/pbkdf2.ts (4.18KB)
          └─┬ https://deno.land/std@0.83.0/node/buffer.ts (15.46KB)
            └─┬ https://deno.land/std@0.83.0/node/_utils.ts (5.74KB)
              └─┬ https://deno.land/std@0.83.0/async/mod.ts (202B)
                └── https://deno.land/std@0.83.0/async/pool.ts (1.58KB)
```

The problematic module is at the bottom of a series of nested imports from the `std` library, which lead up to [`mongo/deps.ts`](https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.22.0/deps.ts) and [`mongo/mod.ts`](https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.22.0/mod.ts), which is being imported by `./controllers/controller.ts` (which is the first module that you can directly edit to fix the problem).

Now I'll pause for a moment to revisit `std` modules:

At https://deno.land/std@0.116.0#releases it says this:

> Standard library is currently tagged independently of Deno version. This will change once the library is stabilized.
>
> To check compatibility of different version of standard library with Deno CLI see [this list](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/denoland/deno_website2/main/versions.json).

What this means is that each version of the `std` library is only guaranteed to be compatible with a specific version of Deno.

The version of the `std` library currently being used by the mongo module in your program is v`0.83.0`, and, referencing the linked compatibility JSON list above, you can find that it maps to Deno v`1.6.3` (which is quite old).

At this point, your most accessible options are:

1. to use a version of Deno compatible with that version of the mongo module (using an old version of Deno is probably not the best idea), or
2. to use a version of the mongo module which is compatible with a newer version of Deno (let's try this one first)

Let's see what the latest version of the mongo module is:

[`https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.28.0/deps.ts`](https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.28.0/deps.ts) is the latest version right now, and it uses v`0.111.0` of the `std` library.

Let's try updating the version of the mongo module in your program and see if it fixes the compiler error:

`./controllers/controller.ts` (line 8):

```ts
// before:
// import {MongoClient} from "https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.22.0/mod.ts";

// after:
import {MongoClient} from "https://deno.land/x/mongo@v0.28.0/mod.ts";
```

Now let's type check and cache your entrypoint again:

```
% deno cache server.ts
```

No compiler error this time!